# Yii an Memcache

Tags: php, caching, yii, memcached

We are using Yii framework and Memcached for caching.

We have the following problem:

1. We make a db query q
2. if q is already cached we get the data from memcache
3. Otherwise yii queries Mysql
4. set the cache value
5. we get back the results from memcache

If we request again the same query q before the memcache key is set ( before step 4 )
then because memcache key is not set we again query the db.

We would like to change this behavior to something like:

1. We make a db query q
2. if key for q exists in memcache and value is not null return value
3. Otherwise if key is set and value is null set memcache key => null
4. set the cache value
5. we get back the results from memcache

Here is the pseudocode of what happens and what we want:

```
get(q):
    if q not in memcache:
        value = query_db(q)
        memcache[q] = value
        return memcache[q]
    else:
        return memcache[q]

getNew(q):
    if q not in memcache:
        memcache[q] = null
        value = query_db(q)
        memcache[q] = value
        return memcache[q]
    elif q in memcache and memcache[q] != null:
        return memcache[q]
    else:
        while True:
            if memcached[q] != null:
                return memcached[q]
            else:
               sleep(3)
```

In other words, we would like to set the memcache key before having the results to null, and the other requests for the same query check if the value is null and wait until the value is not null (it means that the query is already processing).

Do you know which part of the yii frameworkd should be modified?

Comment: In other words, what you really want is something like a locking mechanism: On consecutive queries you want to wait for the result from the first query instead of sending another query to DB, right?

Comment: That's not easy to achieve, if not impossible. The caching logic is buried deeply into some DB core classes. Look for example into `CDbCommand::queryInternal`. Even if you rewrite this method, you can't replace these classes without touching framework files - which is highly discouraged.

Comment: Yes I found where I can do it but I do not like at all to change the framework files. Definetely it is not impossible but I would not do it finally. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Mysql has these system wide locking functions that could help: [`get_lock`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_get-lock) and [`release_lock`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_release-lock)
These take lock name string.

The idea is to do regular memcache check which you already have, then also check if this exact query itself has gone in processing using the lock name. For this, every query will need a unique lock name. Lock name can be made using hex of `crc32($sql)` (fastest non-crypto hashing algo in php) which will make a 4 char unique hex string for every query.

`TIMEOUT` can be a big number

```
getNew(q):
    if q not in memcache:
        hash = crc32hex(q)
        if mysql-is_free(hash) == 0 # means query is processing
            # now attach youself to the other thread's synchronous exit
            if(mysql-get_lock(hash,TIMEOUT)==1) #waiting...
                release_lock(hash)
                # call self since by now, memcache has your value
                return getNew(q)                     
            endif
        endif
        if(mysql-get_lock(hash,TIMEOUT)==1)  
            value = query_db(q)  
            memcache[q] = value
            mysql-release_lock(hash)
        endif
        return memcache[q]
    else:
        return memcache[q]
```

Comment: Seems nice idea, but i abandoned the idea because it requires to change yii's core files and this will cause problems while updating yii or maybe it has some unpredictable side effects.